# Need help in extracting data from list of dictionaries with time lines and counts

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, datetime

Hi I am looking to calculate few things from python list of dictionaries where the data looks as given below. When Name="TOM" I want the count of city, country key and country. The filed I wanted to calculate from the below format table is clearly mentioned after the data please review and suggest a best way to get the calculations

```
people = [
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "city": "NewYork", "Date":2021-01-04 08:37:19Z},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "country": "Japan", "Date": 2021-01-06 08:37:24Z},
    {"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "city": "London", "Date": 2021-01-04 09:26:38Z},
    {"name": "Tom", "hight": 163, "city": "California", "Date": 2021-01-08 12:50:17Z},
    {"name": "Lena", "weight": 45, "country": "Italy", "Date": 2021-01-08 12:50:17Z},
    {"name": "Ben", "age": 17, "city": "Colombo", "Date": 2021-01-21 09:56:04Z},
    {"name": "Lena", "gender": "Female", "country": "Italy", "Date": 2021-01-21 09:56:04Z},
    {"name": "Ben", "gender": "Male", "city": "Colombo", "Date": 2021-02-09 08:47:26Z},
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "country": "Italy", "Date": 2021-02-09 08:47:26Z},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "country": "Japan", "Date": 2021-02-23 09:10:59Z},
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 7, "city": "London", "Date": 2021-03-08 09:39:28Z},
    {"name": "Tom", "hight": 163, "country": "Japan", "Date": 2021-03-08 09:39:28Z},
]
```

expecting output in the following format,

Name:12

Tom: 5

city:3

Data count with Time line,

City: NewYork

Jan:1, feb:2, Mar:2

City: London

Jan:2, Feb:1, Mar:4

```
I have 1000s of these data in list of dictionaries format with lot of other parameters. I am new to this and can some please help getting this solved
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a matter of thinking about "what do I have" and "what do I need", step by step.

```
people = [
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "city": "NewYork", "Date": '01/01/2021'},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "country": "Japan", "Date": '05/01/2021'},
    {"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "city": "London", "Date": '03/06/2021'},
    {"name": "Tom", "hight": 163, "city": "California", "Date": '04/06/2021'},
    {"name": "Lena", "weight": 45, "country": "Italy", "Date": '12/12/2020'},
    {"name": "Ben", "age": 17, "city": "Colombo", "Date": '11/12/2020'},
    {"name": "Lena", "gender": "Female", "country": "Italy", "Date": '8/01/2020'},
    {"name": "Ben", "gender": "Male", "city": "Colombo", "Date": '7/01/2020'},
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 10, "country": "Italy", "Date": '01/01/2021'},
    {"name": "Mark", "age": 5, "country": "Japan", "Date": '05/01/2021'},
    {"name": "Tom", "age": 7, "city": "London", "Date": '03/06/2021'},
    {"name": "Tom", "hight": 163, "country": "Japan", "Date": '04/06/2021'}
]

def groupby( fld ):
    vals = { fld: 0 }
    for row in people:
        if fld in row:
            vals[fld] += 1
            if row[fld] not in vals:
                vals[row[fld]] = 1
            else:
                vals[row[fld]] += 1
    return vals

months = ('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')
def groupbydate( fld ):
    vals = {}
    for row in people:
        if fld in row and 'Date' in row:
            month = months[int(row['Date'].lstrip('0').split('/')[0])-1]
            if row[fld] not in vals:
                vals[row[fld]] = {}
            if month not in vals[row[fld]]:
                vals[row[fld]][month] = 1
            else:
                vals[row[fld]][month] += 1
    return vals

print( groupby( 'name' ) )
print( groupby( 'city' ) )
print( groupby( 'country' ) )
print( )
print( groupbydate( 'city' ) )
```

Output:

```
{'name': 12, 'Tom': 5, 'Mark': 2, 'Pam': 1, 'Lena': 2, 'Ben': 2}
{'city': 6, 'NewYork': 1, 'London': 2, 'California': 1, 'Colombo': 2}
{'country': 6, 'Japan': 3, 'Italy': 3}

{'NewYork': {'Jan': 1}, 'London': {'Mar': 2}, 'California': {'Apr': 1}, 'Colombo': {'Nov': 1, 'Jul': 1}}
```

Using `collections.defaultdict` would make this a bit shorter:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def groupby( fld ):
    vals = defaultdict(int)
    for row in people:
        if fld in row:
            vals[fld] += 1
            vals[row[fld]] += 1
    return dict(vals)

months = ('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')
def groupbydate( fld ):
    vals = {}
    for row in people:
        if fld in row and 'Date' in row:
            if row[fld] not in vals:
                vals[row[fld]] = defaultdict(int)
            month = months[int(row['Date'].lstrip('0').split('/')[0])-1]
            vals[row[fld]][month] += 1
    return vals

print( groupby( 'name' ) )
print( groupby( 'city' ) )
print( groupby( 'country' ) )
print( groupbydate( 'city' ) )
```

**Followup** adding years

```
def groupbyyear( fld ):
    vals = {}
    for row in people:
        if fld in row and 'Date' in row:
            if row[fld] not in vals:
                vals[row[fld]] = defaultdict(int)
            year = int(row['Date'].split('-')[0])
            vals[row[fld]][year] += 1
    return vals

print( groupby( 'name' ) )
print( groupby( 'city' ) )
print( groupby( 'country' ) )
print( groupbydate( 'city' ) )
print( groupbyyear( 'city' ) )
```

Comment: Thank you...because the date was in 2021-01-04 08:35:58Z ...unable to fetch groupdate function values...how can I fix it

Comment: This is why you should always have your sample data match your actual data.  You can do it as a string by replacing `.lstrip('0').split('/')[0]` with `.split('-')[1].lstrip('0')`.

Comment: Wow...that resolved the issue. And one last thing if I want to include year can I add that

Comment: I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.  You can see what I did as a pattern.

Comment: Tried but not able to do it

Comment: I don't think you did.  I hate it when people won't make a legitimate effort to solve their own problems, especially when I've already provided 90% of the answer.  It really irritates me.